# iOS - Repeat notification every 72 hours

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I want to get notification when app is terminated to notify users that you need to keep app running to get app updates.

I also want to repeat notifications every 72 hours if app is not running.

For now, I have implemented local notification however, I am not able to repeat notifications. Moreover, when I reboot device and app is in background, I do not get notification until I relaunch app manually.

What is the best solution for this scenario, do I need to implement Push notification or is it possible with local notification?

Would anybody mind to help me, I will really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `BGAppRefreshTask` in conjunction with a `BGTaskScheduler`.
First, add a new capability to your target: `Background Modes` and select `Background fetch`.
Next, Register your task identifier in the Info.plist under `Permitted background task scheduler identifiers`. e.g. `UpdateApp`

further explanation and details: [Apple Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

you can use this for your current idea of notifying the user every 72 hours, or you can just perform the app updates in the background using a `BGProcessingTask` instead of a `BGAppRefreshTask` if the updates require more time to complete than a simple refresh task.

Comment: My app is getting notifications in background after adding code:

        bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName:"MyBackgroundTask", expirationHandler: {() -> Void in
             UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.bgTask)
            self.bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
        })
        

However, when my app is in background and I reboot the device, then I am not getting notifications until I re-open app manually. I do not want to open app  after reboot as it is already in background.

Comment: the background task will not be performed when an app is foregrounded. so you need to schedule tasks accordingly, like as the app enters the background, and after the initial task is performed, reschedule as part of that task.

Comment: Okay, but will this resolve problem for reboot device that I am not getting notifications after rebooting device when app is already in  background and I do not launch it manually?